# What could make gitversion compute a different version on the same branch (local vs build agent repos)

Tags: git, tfs-2015, gitversion

I have a branch that is committed and synced to TFS 2015.

When running a build on the build agent the gitversion command executed computes a different version.

**Locally I get 3.11.0 based on tag 3.10.0.202**

[image: Local repo gives 3.11.0]

**On the build agent I get 0.1.0**

[image: Build server repo gives 3.11.0]

I feel the change may be related to how the clone is done on the build agent. Can anyone suggest if that seems likely and what might be the difference?

**N.B.**

- The build agent is just a TFS 2015 build agent running on my machine at present.
- Running the command without no fetch gives the same results
- This is the tag [image: tag]
- The wrong version number was on the build server (via TFS build) but I also reproduced it using the command line. I only posted the latter as it gave the results. I can post an example of the TFS build output when I'm next able to log in the server. The repo in the second example (D:) is the one cloned using the TFS build, while the first one (C:) was cloned using VS 2015.

Comment: How did you run the build? Was the build server you mentioned TFS build machine? According to the screenshot,  it seems you didn't use TFS build to run the Git project.

Comment: Have edited the question. I did use TFS build to do the work. It gave the same version number and I reproduced it from the command line. As I stated, the build machine is TFS 2015 Build agent that is running on my machine (I have multiple agents on different machines and the builds give the same results on all of them). I've added more info. I suspect it's the clone, but I'm still new to GIT am trying to understand the logical routes that git version could have used to come up with different versions.

Comment: I'm using GitVersion (through the TFS Task) with TFS 2015 build and it works fine in my case. I don't see anything wrong based on your description, but I'm not very familiar with the involved code. You could try to ask at https://gitter.im/GitTools/GitVersion to get a better reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario by creating a Tag to a history of a branch, and running the gitversion command:
[image]

Then I committed and pushed this branch to TFS 2015, on build agent machine, I ran the gitversion command:
[image]

In order to found out why they were different, I logged into TFS build agent machine and pulled the branch, I found there was no tag on the branch. That's because using sync or push in Visual Studio would not push the tag.

While GitVersion Docs mentions, if a commit is tagged, then GitVersion will always use that version over any calculated versions. This is so if you rebuild a tag then the same version will be produced.

In conclusion, VS doesn't push the Tag cause this difference. To push the Tag, you have to use command `git push --tags`.

Comment: Thankyou. I will check this as soon as I'm in the office in a few hours. However i have one question, my tag is listed on origin not local. If this is true then do think this is a fault with my tagging technique (inasmuch that i shoukd rtfm) or a flaw with the git synch/push mplementation in visual studio?

Comment: Thanks again for detailed explanation.. I've confirmed this behaviour in my example.